# UITableview Cell Won't resize correctly on iPad screen size

Tags: swift, uitableview

When running my app on iPad the display is stretched and the width and height of the UITableview Cell isn't auto resize to iPad's screen size. I tried everything possible with constraints an still it looks wrong

[the correct appearance on iPhone:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0A8s.png)

[the wrong appearance on iPad:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJab9.jpg)

[the cell structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxyNJ.png)

[the UItableview:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4egX.png)

the view controller code:

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  FinalProject
//
//  Created by Matan Levi on 7.11.2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Matan Levi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstTableViewOutlet: UITableView!



    var srt = ""
    var nowPlaying : [Movie] = []
    var srtNew = ""
    var onAirNow : [TvShow] = []
    var getNowPlayingMoviesBool = false
    var getOnAirTvShows = false



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        title = "WatchIt"

        ApiHandler.shared.getMoviesGeners()
        ApiHandler.shared.getTvShowsGeneres()
        ApiHandler.shared.getNowPlayingMovies{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getNowPlayingMoviesBool = true; self.firstTableViewOutlet.reloadData()
            }
        }

        ApiHandler.shared.getTvShowsAiringNow {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getOnAirTvShows = true; self.firstTableViewOutlet.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let firstCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        uiMakeShadowDesign(viewForShadowDesign: firstCell.mainViewShadowOutletNew)
        uiMakeDesign(viewForDesign: firstCell.mainViewOutletNew)
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            if getNowPlayingMoviesBool == true
            {
                firstCell.mainLabel.text = "In Theaters"
                firstCell.imageViewOne.makeImageFromString(imageString: AppManager.shared.nowPlayingMovies[0].posterPath)
                firstCell.imageViewTwo.makeImageFromString(imageString: AppManager.shared.nowPlayingMovies[1].posterPath)
                for i in 0...8
                {
                    self.srt += "\(AppManager.shared.nowPlayingMovies[i].title),"
                }
                firstCell.names.text = srt
            }
        case 1:
            if getOnAirTvShows == true
            {
                firstCell.mainLabel.text = "On Air"
                firstCell.imageViewOne.makeImageFromString(imageString: AppManager.shared.onAirNow[0].posterPath)
                firstCell.imageViewTwo.makeImageFromString(imageString: AppManager.shared.onAirNow[1].posterPath)
                for i in 0...8
                {
                    self.srtNew += "\(AppManager.shared.onAirNow[i].name),"
                }
                firstCell.names.text = srtNew
            }

        default:
            break
        }


        return firstCell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }




    func uiMakeDesign(viewForDesign : UIView)
    {
        viewForDesign.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        viewForDesign.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        viewForDesign.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func uiMakeShadowDesign(viewForShadowDesign : UIView)
    {
        viewForShadowDesign.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        viewForShadowDesign.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        viewForShadowDesign.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        viewForShadowDesign.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let selectedIndexPath = firstTableViewOutlet.indexPathForSelectedRow

        {
            if let inTheatereOrOnAirNowViewController = segue.destination as? InTheatersOrOnAirNowViewController
            {
                inTheatereOrOnAirNowViewController.movieOrTvShow = selectedIndexPath.row
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The problem with the iPad is it shows iPhone 4s size in iPad and you are developing an app which runs on iPhone that's the reason you got stretched layout, run it on iPhone and everything will be okay

Comment: You need to pass different height for iPad in tableview row delegate.

Comment: How do you *want* it to look? As you've laid it out, the images are approximately square... Do you want them square on larger screens (or when the device is rotated)? Or do you want a "max height" with empty space on right/left/between?

Comment: I want the iPad display will autoresize the ui image and the uiview that in the custom cell so it be bigger, square cell

Comment: Based on your screenshot, the height is approximately 82% of the width in the iPhone. If you want to maintain the same ratio, set layout anchors as follows `mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.82, constant: 0).isActive = true`. The width of the iPad would be different from that of the iPhone, so the height would vary but would be proportional.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want it scaled like that? Here are example images of how it will look on an iPhone 8+ and an iPad, in Portrait and Landscape orientations: https://imgur.com/a/nIiac

Comment: @user1046037 can you please explain where should I put the code you wrote in your massage?

Comment: Add that code in your custom cell initialisers. I normally do all the constraints programatically. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your View (height) constraint . In Attributed inspector see the constraint then click +(Plus) then click on height tab and change it **(Regular to Compact)** and then click Add Variant .

After give wC hC (Constraint) according to you.

It will work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDwez.png)

Comment: Thanks! I managed to figure it out and it looks like I wanted